# Maurer Cartan one form

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm a physics student and I'm studying differential geometry, my main reference for the topics about manifolds and Lie groups is Nakahara textbook (chap.5).
My problem is about Maurer-Cartan one-form, Nakahara defines it as a Lie algebra valued one form $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
\theta: X \rightarrow {(L_{g})}_{*}^{-1}X
\end{equation}
where $L_{g}$ is the left action and X a left invariant vector field on the Lie Group G.
Nakahara shows that the Maurer-Cartan form satisfies two relations:

1. **$\theta= V_{\mu} \otimes \theta^{\mu}$**
   (it can we written as a tensor product of generators $V_{\mu}$ and left invariant one forms ${\theta}^{\mu}$)
2. Satisfies the equation: \begin{equation}
   d\theta+ \frac{1}{2} [V_{\mu}, V_{\nu}] \otimes \theta^{\mu} \wedge \theta^{\nu}=0
   \end{equation}
   where d is the exterior derivative.

My problem is that my professor always uses the fact that $\theta= g^{-1}dg$ ($*$) to perform different calculations, and I don't understand how this definition is connected to Nakahara. Besides, I find that the definition ($*$) is not a good one: in my understanding it doesn't make sense to consider an exterior derivative on a group element g, since it is defined only on one-forms.
I think I'm missing something and I hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you searched this site for other questions in this very topic? You’ll find a number of answers to your question.

Comment: Yes I read your answer to a similar question, but it doesn't solve my doubts, which are explained in this question I posted. I think that the symbol dg does not represent an exterior derivative, and I'm asking for a formal way to introduce it in the context I wrote above

Comment: It *does* represent the exterior derivative. Why do you think it does not? That's the issue. I explained in one or two answers that $g$ represents the identity map, not an element of $G$. Write this out explicitly with matrices so that you can identify $L_g$ with actual matrix multiplication. Differentiating $\theta = g^{-1}dg$ gives (essentially) the same result (you have to worry about signs and constants when you work with vector-valued forms) when you write it in coordinates: $d\theta = -g^{-1}dg\,g^{-1}\wedge dg = -\theta\wedge\theta$. BTW, to say $d$ is defined only on $1$-forms?

Comment: Ok, but the identity map g is not a scalar function (0-form), in this case I would agree that dg is a one-form. It maps G in G and, if I introduce a chart, I am mapping matrices in matrices, right?
 In my homework I did a calculation with SU(2) matrices and I found the left invariant vector fields by using $\theta=g^{-1}dg$, so I can see how the "d" should work, but I feel like theoretically I am not fully convinced. (Sorry I edited the question, exterior derivative is defined on n-forms). I really appreciate your help and if you want to suggest a book  for reference it would be great

Comment: Here are two possible sources. Chern/Chen/Lam *Lectures on Differential Geometry*, Chapter 6. Phillip Griffiths, "On Cartan's Method of Lie Groups and Moving Frames As Applied to Uniqueness and Existence Questions in Differential Geometry," Duke Math J. 41  (1974), 775-814.

Comment: I wrote this answer some days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4539224/601797. Maybe it is useful to you